# add sub menus in the sidebar of mxgraph editor?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, draw.io

is it possible to add submenu in mxgraph editor sidebar ? I need many shapes and i wont be able to find them if i cant make submenu
Example :

-General :

--Circles :

---all circles shapes here-

--Squares :

---Rounded Squares :

-all rounded squares shapes here-

--Arrows
-all arrrows here-

[image]

https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html

https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/js/Sidebar.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a palette for each one.
Just like with General, there is a generalPalette which contains the shapes.
Add a new CirclesPalette and add the shapes to it. The same with the squareshapes.

Comment: Yes i did that but iv 1200 custom shapes thats why i need sub menu to order them. I tried with jquery once library is fully loaded but i think this is not the best way...